# detect minor mode activation

Tags: minor-mode

Is there a way to detect when a minor mode is turned on. For `web-mode`, I would like to know when `indent-tabs-mode` is turned on.

Please note that what I need is to detect this when the user has begun to edit the buffer with `indent-tabs-mode` turned off and then decides to turn it on.

Comment: `indent-tabs-mode` is not a mode, it's a variable. Very confusing, I know.

Comment: Can `(if '(indent-tabs-mode) ...` help?

Comment: you're right ... that's obvious ! I guess I'll have to follow the thread on emacs-devel about a hook on variable value change

Comment: Why not simply turn it on in web-mode?

Comment: @Name that will always be true.

Comment: @fxbois this looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/152925). Instead, ask us what you're really trying to do, and we might have better solutions than the one you thought of. ;-) _(And don't hold your breath for that variable hook thread.)_

Answer (score 1):

You can test the truth value of the variable `indent-tabs-mode`, which will be `nil` if it's off and non-`nil` if it's on.

For your specific use case, making sure it's turned on as of the first edit, you can add a little function to `first-change-hook`.  From the docstring:

> Documentation:
>   A list of functions to call before changing a buffer which is unmodified.
>   The functions are run using the `run-hooks` function.

So, you could test for a `nil` value, but since you always want it turned on, you could skip the test:

```
(defun force-tabs-in-web-mode ()
  (when (eq major-mode 'web-mode)  ; I'm assuming it's web-mode
    (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))

(add-hook 'first-change-hook #'force-tabs-in-web-mode)
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood his second paragraph. In the cases where `indent-tabs-mode` is initially off, he wants to detect if the user turns it on some time *after* he started editing the buffer. He doesn't want to detect whether it's turned on at the time of first change. Anyway, that's what it seems to me.

Comment: @Malabarba: after re-reading, I think you're right.  I agree with the comment you left on OP's question: a revised question will probably get more useful answers.

Comment: @Malabarba you're totally right

Answer (score 1):

If you want to respect the user's indentation choice (as you should), the right way is to just do the right thing when indenting, you don't need to keep track if the variable was changed.

Your two options are:

- Instead of manually removing/inserting whitespace at beginning-of-line, just use either `indent-to` or `indent-line-to`. These functions automatically respect the `indent-tabs-mode` variable.
- If you need to do it manually for some reason, just check the value of `indent-tabs-mode` inside your indentation function and act accordingly.

Comment: You summarize a little bit too much. To deal with tab indentation I need to change some parameters (especially lineup params) ... please look at web-mode-use-tabs

Comment: @fxbois sure, I'll look into it tomorrow. But, by the name, it sounds like this parameter is just duplicating the functionality of indent-tabs-mode. If that's the case you simply shouldn't have such a parameter, you should simply look at indent-tabs-mode.

Answer (score 0):

From the emacs manual's section on minor modes:

> Most minor modes also have a "mode variable", with the same name as
>   the mode command.  Its value is non-`nil` if the mode is enabled, and
>   `nil` if it is disabled.

For example, associated to `abbrev-mode`, the function and minor mode, there is the variable `abbrev-mode` whose documentation is:

> abbrev-mode is a variable defined in `C source code'. Its value is nil
>
> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.   This variable is safe
>   as a file local variable if its value   satisfies the predicate
>   `booleanp`.
>
> Documentation: Non-nil if Abbrev mode is enabled. Use the command
>   `abbrev-mode` to change this variable.

As this indicates, in general the variable should be changed via the command.

As mentioned in the comments the case of `indent-tab-mode` is unusual, there is no corresponding function, just the variable.  Anyway you can test for whether it is set or not via

```
(if indent-tab-mode
    (do-true-action)
    (do-false-action))
```

Comment: I know this, as I have written, I need to know when this var has its value changed. As you wrote it, detecting if a minor mode is turned on is easy. What I need to know is when this minor mode is toggled.

Comment: @fxbois Provide a little more context on why you need that, and we may be able to provide an alternate solution.

Comment: @Malabarba to adjust web-mode settings to play nicely with tab indentation requirements.

Comment: Then your question is not clear to me.  Why not set a variable to the value of `indent-tab-mode` when the `web-mode` starts and compare the current value of `indent-tab-mode` to that?

Comment: I won't compare this each time I indent a line. I was wondering if a cleaner solution existed.